# React Router url with params

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I use React Router on a MeteorJS framework.

I would like create new slug with **/blog/:slug**, but no result. My PostItem component :

```
class PostsListItem extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <li className={this.props.post.draft ? 'is-drafted' : ''}>
        <Link to={`/blog/${this.props.post.slug}`}>{this.props.post.title}</Link>
        <p>{this.props.post.description}</p>
      </li>
    );
  }

}
```

My routing :

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <main className="l-main">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
              <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
              <Route path='/blog/:slug' component={Article} />
              <Route path='/about' component={About} />
              <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

And my Article components (for display my **/blog/:slug** url) :

```
function Article(props) {
  return <h1>{props.match.params.name}</h1>
}
```

I don't understand why my page don't display. If i test /blog/test-slug, i see the parent route : `<Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />`

Anyone have any idea ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're doing this:

```
<Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
<Route path='/blog/:slug' component={Article} />
```

instead of this:

```
<Route exact path='/blog' component={Blog} />
<Route path='/blog/:slug' component={Article} />
```

The router is searching for the first matching URL. And if you're not giving the "exact" attribute, everything with "/blog" matches. Doesn't matter what comes after that.